# update date in database after user login successfull asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to record that last update of user that log in into my  website. After they  log in success, the laseUpdate filed must change to the current date time.

I have use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ICEWeb.Models
{

public class CustomerModels:ItemEntityDataContext
{

    public bool ValidateCustomer(string username, string password)
    {

        bool b = (

                    this.DataContext
                        .Customers
                        .Where(s => s.ActiveInWebLogin == 1
                                    &&
                                    s.WebAccount == username
                                    &&
                                    s.Password == password
                               )
                        .SingleOrDefault()

                 ) != null;

        if (b == true)
            this.UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus();

        return b;

    }
    public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus()
    {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;
        this.DataContext.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

}

The validateCustomer() is work but it is not update my record(LastWebLogIn).
Can anyone solve this for me?
Thanks.

Comment: You are creating new Customer object in UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus method. Isn't that has to be some particular customer, for whom you want to update the time? In your case the framework doesn't know for which field, it should update the time.

Comment: All the customers, when they log in the second time, the lastUpdate field must update.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve but you will have to explicitly tell the framework the "customer" for whom you want to update the time. When you create new Customer, there is nothing in database corresponding to him, so nothing gets updated. Kindly have a look at the answers people have given in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Table.InsertOnSubmit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb763516.aspx) if you want to create new Customer:

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;

this.DataContext.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
this.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

If you want to update existing customer you should do following:

```
var customer = this.DataContext.Customers
    .Where(...)
    .Single();

customer.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;
this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new instance but ise the current instance of the Customers object and update it to the database. Try something like this:

```
public bool ValidateCustomer(string username, string password) 
{ 
    var user = this.DataContext.Customers 
                               .Where(s => s.ActiveInWebLogin == 1 && 
                                s.WebAccount == username && 
                                s.Password == password) 
                               .SingleOrDefault(); 

    if (user != null)
    { 
        this.UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(user); 
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(Customers c) 
{ 
    c.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now; 
    this.DataContext.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `LastWebLogIn` for an unidentified new customer. Take the customer from the database (as per your first method), and update that object (making sure you haven't optimised with a read-only data-context).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code :

```
public bool ValidateCustomer(string username, string password)
    {

         var customer =           this.DataContext
                        .Customers
                        .Where(s => s.ActiveInWebLogin == 1
                                    &&
                                    s.WebAccount == username
                                    &&
                                    s.Password == password
                               )
                        .SingleOrDefault()

        if (customer != null)
            return this.UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(customer);

        return false;

    }
    public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(Customer c)
    {
        try
        {
            c.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;
            this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        Catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error
            return false;
        }
    }
```